# I have Ruby 1.9.3dev, why not 1.9.3-p0?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm using RVM to manage my versions of Ruby.

When I do "RVM list known" I get:

```
Adams-MacBook-Pro:~ adam$ rvm list known
# MRI Rubies
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.6-head
[ruby-]1.8.7[-p352]
[ruby-]1.8.7-head
[ruby-]1.9.1-p378
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.1-head
[ruby-]1.9.2-p180
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p290]
[ruby-]1.9.2-head
[ruby-]1.9.3[-preview1]
[ruby-]1.9.3-head
ruby-head
```

I installed Ruby 1.9.3 doing "rvm install 1.9.3".
When I installed it I got:

```
Adams-MacBook-Pro:~ adam$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3dev (2011-07-31 revision 32789) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
```

How come I have "dev" and not "p0"? How do I get "p0"?

In case you're curious:

```
Adams-MacBook-Pro:~ adam$ rvm -v

rvm 1.8.3 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update the rvm to get the latest list of available rubies. At the moment, the latest stable version of rvm is 1.10.2.

For more information, visit http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/upgrading/

Comment: +1 for resolving my compilation errors when I had tried installing 1.9.3. I was on rvm 1.1!

Comment: @ranedra "rvm get stable" doesn't work for me. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: @NewB: Try rvm help for more information and see if head or stable is listed as a command or not. And also it is safe to simply re-run the installation script again to get the latest version.